# How can I call click function to another click function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 button. When I click in button 1 then button 2 is disable, and when button 1 was closed then button 2 is enable. I am using trigger("click") then occur error 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'. How can I solve this problem.

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
        $('#box1').css('display','block');
        $('#box1').addClass('tint');
        $("#btn2").off('click');
    });
$("#btn2").click(function(){
        alert("Button 2 was clicked");
    });
$('#boxclose1').click(function(){
        $('#box1').hide();
        $("#btn2").on("click", function(){
            $('#btn2').trigger("click"); error here
        });
    });
```

Comment: You are triggering the click event within the click handler, it amounts to doing this: `function r(){ r(); }` Why are your doing that? Are you meaning to trigger the event after you turned the listener back on?

Comment: Because calling trigger will call the `$("#btn2").on("click", function(){` handler which will call the trigger again causing an infinite recursive call

Comment: Why do you want to call the trigger method

Comment: "I have 2 button. When I click in button 1 then button 2 is disable" if disable use '.prop("disabled",false);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine

You can use

`.prop("disabled",true);` to disable and

`.prop("disabled",false);` to enable button

```js
$("#btn1").click(function(){
        $('#box1').css('display','block');
        $('#box1').addClass('tint');
        $("#btn2").prop('disabled', true);
    });
$("#btn2").click(function(){
        alert("Button 2 was clicked");
    });
$('#boxclose1').click(function(){
        $('#box1').hide();
        $('#btn2').prop('disabled', false);
    });
```

```css
#box1 {
  display:none;
}
.tint {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<div id="box1">Box 1</div>
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>
<button id="boxclose1">Box Close</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#btn2").on("click", function(){
        $('#btn2').trigger("click"); error here
    });
```

This is kinda recursive call of function bind to click event on element #btn2